# the availability of data on quarterly and monthly world economic growth, specifically the GDP growth rate

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data, economics, gdp

I would greatly appreciate if you could help me to obtain access to reliable and up-to-date data on world economic growth or the GDP growth rates at both the quarterly and monthly levels. [This](https://www.imf.org/external/datamapper/NGDP_RPCH@WEO/OEMDC/ADVEC/WEOWORLD) is just annually.

Answer (score 1):

Not monthly, but You can get both annually and quarterly past, current as well as forecasted GDP data along with several other factors. Data IMF Org. have service named [**GDP and components**](https://data.imf.org/regular.aspx?key=61545852) where you can get data for all countries.
You can export data very easily from here in csv, xlsx and other formats.
[image: Screenshot of GDP and Components from Data IMF Org.]

Comment: Thanks a lot but when I select "world", it does not display any data.